convert an ipynb file with ipywidgets to an executable
is there a way to convert an ipynb file with ipywidgets to an executable?
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import VBox

run_button = widgets.Button(description = "Run", disabled=False)

def userInput():
     return VBox([run_button])

userInput()
print("hello world")

of course there would be other UI elements and functions, but this is just a really basic example
i've converted this ipynb file to a py file using nbconvert
py -m nbconvert "test.ipynb"
and i've converted the resulting py file to an exe using PyInstaller
py -m PyInstaller --onefile "test.py"
however when i run the exe (from the dist folder), nothing happens. i tried running the exe from a cmd window instead of double clicking the file, and although print() statements will show, my GUI (the example above, just a single button) will not show
any advice? thanks!

I think you are asking something along the lines of covered here, yet with an emphasis on ipywidgets use. nteract supports ipywidgets. You could potentially use voici these days, although it is in the early stage of development still. Instead of ipywidgets: you'd typically use PyQt/PySide if you were developing an executable the last few years. There's also Pysimplegui & PyGUI.

 Also.... from here: "I‘m using streamlit. It starts a little server and you can access it through a browser. It is directly implemented into your code. Simply import streamlit as st.". Note for connecting things, that states sort of what I was thinking you can do now with Voici because Python's SimpleHTTPServer makes it easy to share a local server with our browser & then you can stay with Ipywidgets.
